# Enabling cookies with urllib

Tags: python, cookies, urllib

I would like to parse a website with `urllib` python library. I wrote this:

```
import urllib as web
source_rep.urlopen(url_rep).read()
print source_rep
```

The website returns to me a message saying that I should enable cookie. How can I do that with python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a [`CookieJar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookiejar-and-filecookiejar-objects), of course!

And [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).

```
import cookielib
import urllib2
cookiejar= cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
opener= urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar) )
opener.urlopen(...)
```

---

As an aside:

In my experience, a site you want to parse telling you to enable cookies is a good indicator this is going to be a unpleasant experience, and you'll be asking `how to enable javascript in urllib2` next (which is not really answerable, by the way).

If you think you'll benefit from a higher-level approach, you should probably evaluate [`mechanize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize) and [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 4):

This answer is tested with Python 3.7. I would typically **use a new opener for each random URL** that I want cookies for.

```
from urllib.request import build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor, Request
url = 'https://www.cell.com/cell-metabolism/fulltext/S1550-4131(18)30630-2'
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor())
```

Without a `Request` object:

```
response = opener.open(url, timeout=30)
content = response.read()
```

With a `Request` object:

```
request = Request(url)
response = opener.open(request, timeout=30)
content = response.read()
```